# @RequestMapping & Bound Generic Paramters

Tags: spring-mvc, generics, java-8, request-mapping

The following `@RequestMapping`'s produce an ambiguous request mapping for a `@RestController` in Spring Boot 1.5/Java 8.

Is there a way to 'negate' the generic constraint on the fist method to not include `Iterable`'s? I would prefer to keep the same method name, path etc.. 
(i.e.) A post with an array would go to one method, and a post of a single item would go to the second method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo")
public T save(T item){
    ...
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo")
public Iterable<T> save(Iterable<T> items){
    ...
}
```

Comment: With the parameters you can not define the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is obviously ambiguous.

You need to specify a different endpoint for each saved type, or you can narrow mapping via elements of `@RequestMapping` annotation.

For example you could implement something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", params="item")
public T save(T item){
    ...
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", params="items")
public Iterable<T> save(Iterable<T> items){
    ...
}
```

or, using `headers`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", headers="Input-Type=item")
public T save(T item){
    ...
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/foo", headers="Input-Type=items")
public Iterable<T> save(Iterable<T> items){
    ...
}
```

Comment: great, for some reason I was thinking that the 'Type' of the argument was enough to overload the method.